Cesium Resource Proxy getUrl with AWS SDK v3 presigned url
We are using the Cesium Resource Proxy class to provide a presigned url from s3 for each of our resources. The getUrl method must return a string and is synchronous. When using the AWS SDK v2, this works because getPresignedUrl returns a string. How can I do the same thing using the entirely async AWS SDK v3?

I didn't want to phrase this as "how do I turn async into sync code" because that inevitably leads to a bunch of guff in the feed, and yet...
